# Is white underwear necessary while being baptized in The Church of Jesus Christ of the Latter-day Saints?

Tags: lds, baptism

Is white underwear necessary while being baptized in The Church of Jesus Christ of the Latter-day Saints?

Comment: Welcome to Christianity.SE! I hope you'll spend some time browsing the questions and answers here. For some tips on asking good questions (and avoiding some of the downvotes you're getting on this one), please see, [How do I ask a good question?](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No. White is usually recommended, though. It is more practical, since the jumpsuits are also white.

Comment: Surely this is about modesty and not having a color show through after the white jumpsuits are wet.